# How to generate custom page in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I am a beginner in OpenCart eshop. I am creating a custom page for product description. I have already created the controller, model and view file for custom page at scratch opencart in my local machine. Its working perfectly.model,controller and view name is `Custreview`  I am facing this errror after migrating to live server:

```
Warning: require() [function.require]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/demoosiz/public_html/cart/OpenCart/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 68
Warning: require() [function.require]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/demoosiz/public_html/cart/OpenCart/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 68 
Warning: require() [function.require]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/demoosiz/public_html/cart/OpenCart/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 68
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/demoosiz/public_html/cart/OpenCart/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 68
```

Here my controller file...

```
<?php
class ControllerInformationCustReview extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        /*if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
            $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('account/custreview', '', 'SSL');

            $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
        } */

        $this->language->load('information/custreview');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_name') . ' - ' . $this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('account/custreview');

        $this->getForm();
    } 

    public function insert() {
        $this->load->language('information/custreview');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_name') . ' - ' . $this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('account/custreview');

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {
            $this->model_account_custreview->addReview($this->request->post);

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            $this->redirect($this->url->link('information/custreview'));
        }

        $this->getForm();
    }

    private function getForm() {
        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        $this->data['entry_prefix'] = $this->language->get('entry_prefix');
        $this->data['entry_desc'] = $this->language->get('entry_desc');
        $this->data['entry_industry'] = $this->language->get('entry_industry');
        $this->data['entry_design'] = $this->language->get('entry_design');
        $this->data['entry_prefix1'] = $this->language->get('entry_prefix1');
        $this->data['entry_other'] = $this->language->get('entry_other');
        $this->data['entry_prefix2'] = $this->language->get('entry_prefix2');
        $this->data['entry_prefix3'] = $this->language->get('entry_prefix3');
        $this->data['entry_prefix4'] = $this->language->get('entry_prefix4');

        $this->data['logged'] = $this->customer->getFirstname() . ' ' . $this->customer->getLastName();

        $this->data['text_none'] = $this->language->get('text_none');
        $this->data['text_select'] = $this->language->get('text_select');

        $this->data['entry_product'] = $this->language->get('entry_product');
        $this->data['entry_author'] = $this->language->get('entry_author');
        $this->data['entry_rating'] = $this->language->get('entry_rating');
        $this->data['entry_review'] = $this->language->get('entry_review');
        $this->data['entry_good'] = $this->language->get('entry_good');
        $this->data['entry_bad'] = $this->language->get('entry_bad');

        $this->data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('continue_shop');
$this->data['button_checkout'] = $this->language->get('check_out');

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->session->data['success'])) {
            $this->data['success'] = $this->session->data['success'];

            unset($this->session->data['success']);
        } else {
            $this->data['success'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['product'])) {
            $this->data['error_product'] = $this->error['product'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_product'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['product_id'])) {
            $this->data['error_product_id'] = $this->error['product_id'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_product_id'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['author'])) {
            $this->data['error_author'] = $this->error['author'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_author'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['text'])) {
            $this->data['error_text'] = $this->error['text'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_text'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['rating'])) {
            $this->data['error_rating'] = $this->error['rating'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_rating'] = '';
        }   
        if (isset($this->error['cdesc'])) {
            $this->data['error_desc'] = $this->error['cdesc'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_desc'] = '';
        }
        if (isset($this->error['industry'])) {
            $this->data['error_industry'] = $this->error['industry'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_industry'] = '';
        }
        if (isset($this->error['design'])) {
            $this->data['error_design'] = $this->error['design'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_design'] = '';
        }
        if (isset($this->error['other'])) {
            $this->data['error_other'] = $this->error['other'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_other'] = '';
        }
        if (isset($this->error['file'])) {
            $this->data['error_file'] = $this->error['file'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_file'] = '';
        }

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', 'SSL'),
            'separator' => false
        );

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('information/custreview','SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );

        if (!isset($this->request->get['review_id'])) { 
            $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('information/custreview/insert');
        }

        $this->data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('information/custreview','SSL');

        if (isset($this->request->get['review_id']) && ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')) {
            $review_info = $this->model_account_custreview->getReview($this->request->get['review_id']);
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->data['categories'] = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        if (isset($this->request->post['product_id'])) {
            $this->data['product_id'] = $this->request->post['product_id'];

            $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($this->request->post['product_id']);

            if ($product_info) {
                $this->data['product'] = $product_info['name'];
            } else {
                $this->data['product'] = '';
            }
        } elseif (isset($review_info)) {
            $this->data['product_id'] = $review_info['product_id'];

            $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($review_info['product_id']);

            if ($product_info) {
                $this->data['product'] = $product_info['name'];
            } else {
                $this->data['product'] = '';
            }
        } else {
            $this->data['product_id'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['product_id'])) {
            $this->data['product_id'] = $this->request->post['product_id'];
        } elseif (isset($review_info)) {
            $this->data['product_id'] = $review_info['product_id'];
        } else {
            $this->data['product_id'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['product'])) {
            $this->data['product'] = $this->request->post['product'];
        } elseif (isset($review_info)) {
            $this->data['product'] = $review_info['product'];
        } else {
            $this->data['product'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['author'])) {
            $this->data['author'] = $this->request->post['author'];
        } elseif (isset($review_info)) {
            $this->data['author'] = $review_info['author'];
        } else {
            $this->data['author'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['text'])) {
            $this->data['text'] = $this->request->post['text'];
        } elseif (isset($review_info)) {
            $this->data['text'] = $review_info['text'];
        } else {
            $this->data['text'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['rating'])) {
            $this->data['rating'] = $this->request->post['rating'];
        } elseif (isset($review_info)) {
            $this->data['rating'] = $review_info['rating'];
        } else {
            $this->data['rating'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['cdesc'])) {
            $this->data['cdesc'] = $this->request->post['cdesc'];
        } elseif (isset($review_info)) {
            $this->data['cdesc'] = $review_info['cdesc'];
        } else {
            $this->data['cdesc'] = '';
        }
        if (isset($this->request->post['industry'])) {
            $this->data['industry'] = $this->request->post['industry'];
        } elseif (isset($review_info)) {
            $this->data['industry'] = $review_info['industry'];
        } else {
            $this->data['industry'] = '';
        }
        if (isset($this->request->post['design'])) {
            $this->data['design'] = $this->request->post['design'];
        } elseif (isset($review_info)) {
            $this->data['design'] = $review_info['design'];
        } else {
            $this->data['design'] = '';
        }
        if (isset($this->request->post['other'])) {
            $this->data['other'] = $this->request->post['other'];
        } elseif (isset($review_info)) {
            $this->data['other'] = $review_info['other'];
        } else {
            $this->data['other'] = '';
        }
        if (isset($this->request->post['file'])) {
            $this->data['file'] = $this->request->post['file'];
        } elseif (isset($review_info)) {
            $this->data['file'] = $review_info['file'];
        } else {
            $this->data['file'] = '';
        }

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/custreview.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/custreview.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/information/custreview.tpl';
        }

        $this->children = array(
            'common/column_left',
            'common/column_right',
            'common/content_top',
            'common/content_bottom',
            'common/footer',
            'common/header'     
        );


        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    }

    private function validateForm() {

        /*if (!$this->request->post['product_id']) {
            $this->error['product'] = $this->language->get('error_product');
        }

        if (!$this->request->post['product_id']) {
            $this->error['product_id'] = $this->language->get('error_product_id');
        }*/

        if ((strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['author'])) < 3) || (strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['author'])) > 64)) {
            $this->error['author'] = $this->language->get('error_author');
        }
/*
        if (strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['text'])) < 1) {
            $this->error['text'] = $this->language->get('error_text');
        }*/

        /*if (!isset($this->request->post['rating'])) {
            $this->error['rating'] = $this->language->get('error_rating');
        }*/
        if (!isset($this->request->post['file'])) {
            $this->error['file'] = $this->language->get('error_file');
        }
        if ((strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['cdesc'])) < 3) || (strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['cdesc'])) > 1000)) {
            $this->error['cdesc'] = $this->language->get('error_desc');
        }
        if ((strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['industry'])) < 3) || (strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['industry'])) > 1000)) {
            $this->error['industry'] = $this->language->get('error_industry');
        }
        if ((strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['design'])) < 3) || (strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['design'])) > 1000)) {
            $this->error['design'] = $this->language->get('error_design');
        }
        if ((strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['other'])) < 3) || (strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['other'])) > 1000)) {
            $this->error['other'] = $this->language->get('error_other');
        }

        if (!$this->error) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }   

    public function autocomplete() {
        $json = array();

        if (isset($this->request->post['filter_name'])) {
            $this->load->model('catalog/product');

            $data = array(
                'filter_name' => $this->request->post['filter_name'],
                'start'       => 0,
                'limit'       => 20
            );

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $json[] = array(
                    'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
                    'name'       => html_entity_decode($result['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),   
                    'model'      => $result['model'],
                    'price'      => $result['price']                
                );  
            }
        }

        $this->load->library('json');

        $this->response->setOutput(Json::encode($json));
    }   
}
?>
```

Here my tpl file :

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
       <?php echo $entry_author; ?><br />
       <!-- <input type="text" name="author" value="<?php echo $logged; ?>" />-->
       <textarea name="author" cols="100" rows="1" name="cdesc"><?php echo $logged; ?></textarea>
    <?php if ($error_author) { ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_author; ?></span>
              <?php } ?>
     <p> <?php echo $entry_prefix; ?></p>
    <?php echo $entry_desc; ?><br/>
    <textarea name="cdesc" cols="100" rows="3"></textarea>
        <?php if ($error_desc) { ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_desc; ?></span>
              <?php } ?>
            <br/>  
    <?php echo $entry_industry; ?><br/>
    <textarea name="industry" cols="100" rows="1"></textarea>
    <?php if ($error_industry) { ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_industry; ?></span>
              <?php } ?>    
        <br/>     
    <?php echo $entry_design; ?><br/>
    <textarea name="design" cols="100" rows="4"></textarea>
    <?php if ($error_design) { ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_design; ?></span>
              <?php } ?>
     <p> <?php echo $entry_prefix1; ?></p>  
     <?php echo $entry_other; ?><br/>
    <textarea name="other" cols="100" rows="1"></textarea>
    <?php if ($error_other) { ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_other; ?></span>
              <?php } ?>
     <p><?php echo $entry_prefix2; ?></p>
    <input type="file" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" name="file">
    <?php if ($error_file) { ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_file; ?></span>
              <?php } ?>
    <p><?php echo $entry_prefix3; ?></p>
    <br/>
        <b><?php echo $entry_review; ?></b><br/>
            <textarea name="text"  rows="1"  cols="100"></textarea>
            <?php if ($error_text) { ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_text; ?></span>
              <?php } ?>
              <p><?php echo $entry_prefix4; ?></p>
    <table class="form">
       <tr>
      <div class="buttons"><a href="index.php" class="button" style="margin-left: 5px;"><span><?php echo $button_save; ?></span></a>
      <a onclick="$('#form').submit();" class="button"><span><?php echo $button_checkout; ?></span></a>
      </div>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
```

I need to create custom form which contain company name, organisation name, image upload and so on.further, it moved into cart page like a product.I just modified into my design UI.I get this extension and modified it (refer URL [Opencart extension](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5556%29...i)).further i customized it for my design UI.And I am also using web to print online design tools in opencart.Could You please help me solving this error?

Comment: please guide me.......I am waiting for ur responsive answer....

Comment: **First** - post here Your vQmod file. **Second** - what is the name of the controller, path to the controller and what URL are You opening?

Comment: Hi @shadyyx......I update my post..please some guidelines for this..

Comment: This is the file You have edited? Why did You need to edit this file? What did You edited exactly? This is the main class for **vQmod** and I highly recommend not editing any system source files...

Comment: Hi @shadyyx...thank u for guide me...its more valuable for me..I install web to print extension in opencart,so only i edit this....web2print working perfectly....but i want create custom page in both admin and frontend..its doesn`t working...

Comment: I just install this extension and customized controller,model and view only..here extension name:(http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5556)...i just customized it only..

Comment: Sorry, this info is totaly useless... Remove that vQmod code You have posted here and paste the code from the controller You have edited. Point out what did You changed and why.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27235/discussion-between-display-none-and-shadyyx)

Comment: Hi @shadyyx...I update my post...let me say how to solve this...please guide me.....please refer this link also ...demo.osiztechnologies.com/cart/OpenCart/…..

Answer (score 0):

Clear your vqmod cache folder, if that does not help - check your `system/engine/controller.php` file, error in this vqmod-cached file

Comment: Hi @Oleja.....thank u for responsive answer...I need to create custom page in admin and frontend with this above controller,view and model..How to solve this warning message.....

Answer (score 0):

clearing your vqmod cache may help you. if not try to remove vqmod xml's one by one, you can find the problem file.

http://kvcodes.com/2013/10/create-custom-admin-page-open-cart/